# Default file selection using Application.GetOpenFilename

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following to open a dialog box to select files.

```
fnameListCurr = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Choose CSV files to import", MultiSelect:=True)
```

However, when I do this, nothing is selected by default. Is it possible to have the file selector dialog open with certain files or all files that meet the filter criteria already selected?

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it possible to have the file selector dialog open with certain files or all files that meet the filter criteria already selected". If you know the files path and their names, why do you need a dialog? It is possible to use an Initial Name, not using `GetOpenFilename`...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am not trying to pre-select a specific file. When the file selector window opens, I want all of the filtered files in the folder already selected so that I only have to click OK to load the list of filenames to a variable.

As it stands, when I use `Application.GetOpenFilename`, it opens the file selector window with the files listed but none of them are selected. I have to manually select all of the files before clicking OK.

Although I normally want all of the filtered files, there will be occasions when I only want some of the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set an initial Fine name, use `FileDialog` instead. Try the next code, please:

```
Sub filedialogSelectSomething()
   Dim fileName
   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Choose CSV files to import"
        .InitialFileName = "Your Path\Test*.csv"         
        .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            fileName = .SelectedItems(1)
            'or use them all...
        End If
   End With
   Debug.Print fileName
End Sub
```

Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.initialfilename) to better understand how `InitialFileName` overrides the file filter settings...

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am not trying to override the filter. I want to have all of the filtered files pre-selected so that I can click OK without having to manually select them each time I run the script.

Comment: @GBMedusa: I also want to have money like Bill Gates... If you know which are the files to be selected, why do you need such an interface? Do you like pressing buttons?

Comment: The same files will not be selected every time.

Comment: @GBMedusa:If you know what to be (already selected) you do not need any such interface. You can use instead the next approach: Use the `FileDialog` only in order to select the necessary folder, then iterate between the files inside it, filtering them according to your need. Something like `Dir(FolderPath & "*.csv")`. In such a way all .csv files from that folder can be open one by one, processed and closed.

Comment: @GBMedusa: Or use a name pattern. For instance `Dir(FolderPath & "Test*.csv")` will open all csv files when their name starts with "Test". It will  open `Test1.csv, Test_new.csv` and so on..

Comment: @GBMedusa: Still alive?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but these are not addressing what I am trying to achieve. It looks like I will have to rework my question.

Comment: @GBMedusa: Aren't you able to explain "what you are trying to achieve"? Did you take in consideration the suggestion using `Dir` for a file name pattern?

Comment: I think the problem is that I used the word "selected" instead of "highlighted". I'm trying to open the file selector dialog with all of the files "highlighted" by default. If I can get this to work, I can just click OK when I need to process all of the files (which is most of the time) or, on rare occasions, manually select the ones I need in the file selector dialog and then click OK. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @GBMedusa: This is not possible in standard VBA. Selected or highlighted is the same in this specific case. Since such a thing is not possible, not handled by VBA `GetOpenFilename`, I asked you about your final goal and suggested some other approaches in order to fulfill your need.  If you are stacked on this approach, I wish you success and have a good day!